# Compilation Issues with Android 11 Kernel Source Code on Pixel 4 XL

Tags: linux

I have a Pixel 4 XL and I've downloaded the kernel source code for Android 11. During the compilation process, I followed a method I found online. This involved placing the 'boot.img-ramdisk.cpio' file into the root directory of the source code. I then downloaded 'mkbootimg' and made some modifications to the 'build.sh' script. I executed the compile command with the following parameters:

BUILD_CONFIG=private/msm-google/build.config.floral BUILD_BOOT_IMG=1 MKBOOTIMG_PATH=mkbootimg.py VENDOR_RAMDISK_BINARY=boot.img-ramdisk.cpio KERNEL_BINARY=Image.lz4 BOOT_IMAGE_HEADER_VERSION=2 KERNEL_CMDLINE="console=ttyMSM0,115200n8 androidboot.console=ttyMSM0 printk.devkmsg=on msm_rtb.filter=0x237 ehci-hcd.park=3 service_locator.enable=1 androidboot.memcg=1 cgroup.memory=nokmem usbcore.autosuspend=7 androidboot.usbcontroller=a600000.dwc3 swiotlb=2048 androidboot.boot_devices=soc/1d84000.ufshc loop.max_part=7 buildvariant=user" BASE_ADDRESS=0x00000000 PAGE_SIZE=4096 build/build.sh.

After running the command, I was indeed able to obtain a kernel file with the necessary drivers. However, during the compilation process, it gets stuck for a long time at 'LTO vmlinux'. I'm looking for a way to bypass this. I've tried removing the 'CONFIG_LTO_CLANG' flag, and while it indeed quickly gets past 'vmlinux', the compiled kernel does not include the touchscreen and Wi-Fi drivers. This issue has been bothering me for a long time. If anyone knows a solution to this problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

I tried the official method and modified CONFIG_LTO_CLANG. The resulting kernel file is about 5MB smaller and does not include screen and Wi-Fi drivers.